# Does c# have the same issues like Java with equals and gethashcode()?

Tags: c#, java, equals, gethashcode

Does c# have the same issues like Java with equals and gethashcode?

issues like: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html

Comment: You might want to be a bit more explicit. Which issues do you mean?

Comment: Depends on what you call issues.

Comment: What's the problem with Java's equals and getHashCode?

Answer (score 12):

If you mean that equality is hard to define when it comes to inheritance, yes.

However, .NET has the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface which is frequently used for equality and hashing - for containers such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Almost everything in the framework which needs equality/hashing allows the behaviour to be specified by an `IEqualityComparer<T>`, which means you can express whichever notion of equality you want, if the form given by the type itself is inappropriate for your needs.

Comment: Issues like: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html

Comment: @Blankman: Right - so basically you want two different concepts of equality; one by ID and one by various fields. That's exactly what `IEqualityComparer<T>` is for.

Comment: so Collections use IEqualityComparer<T>? if yes, it seems a little more robust than Java.

Comment: @Blankman: Yes, things like `HashSet<T>` allow you to specify a custom comparator when you create them.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which issues you're talking about since you're a little vague...

But if you mean that you <strike>have</strike> should (if you don't want a compiler warning, or possibly unexpected behavior in your code) to override `GetHashCode` when you override `Equals`, then yes.